# Access testPath inside setupTestFrameworkScriptFile

Tags: jestjs

Is there a way to access `testPath` in `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` code. Currently `testPath` is passed to JasmineReporter (https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/index.js#L37).

Is it possible to obtain this information somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in jest@18.1.0 it can be done in this way:

/path/to/reporter-setup.js

```
function getTestPath() {
  if (Symbol && typeof Symbol.for === 'function') {
    var globalStateKey = Symbol.for('$$jest-matchers-object');
    if (globalStateKey) {
      var globalState = global[globalStateKey];
      if (globalState) {
        var state = globalState.state;
        if (state) {
          return state.testPath;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

jest --setupTestFrameworkScriptFile /path/to/reporter-setup.js